# Symbol 'type <none>.experimental.MultiIOModule' is missing from the classpath

Tags: chisel

I got a build error as following when I tried to build a Chisel module

```
/home/rock/oneStage/src/test/scala/rv32_1stage/TOPTester.scala:15:31
Symbol 'type <none>.experimental.MultiIOModule' is missing from the classpath.
This symbol is required by 'type chisel3.iotesters.PeekPokeTester.T'.
Make sure that type MultiIOModule is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
A full rebuild may help if 'PeekPokeTester.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of <none>.experimental.
class TOPTest(c: TOP) extends PeekPokeTester(c) {
```

The question is that

1. I cann't find the `<none>.experimental.MultiIOModule` under `Chisel3.iotester._/chisel3.experimental._ dir`, where can i find the necessary MultiIOModule?
2. How to use the `-Ylog-classpath`?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This looks like a linkage error, ie. using a version of `chisel-iotesters` that was compiled against one version of `chisel3` while using a newer version of chisel3. Can you share the versions of what you're using? `chisel-iotesters` tend to be 1 minor version ahead of `chisel3`, eg. you should be using `chisel-iotesters` `v1.5.x` with `chisel3` `v3.4.x` (where `x` can be whatever number, we maintain binary compatibility between minor versions).

Answer (score 1):

MultiIOModule, in the more recent versions of Chisel, is in the base chisel3 package, it used to be in package experimental.
So try just using `import chisel3._` and removing the experimental package name. It would be helpful if you could provide a minimal example that exhibits the error. The [scastie website](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/qzrCjP6ZRMm0WK2IzCJB3A) is an excellent tool for doing this (the link here is an example as well). I hope this helps, welcome to Chisel.